# Problemas com mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer com que a pagina exiba os documentos enviados pelo usuário, mas sempre me retorna o mesmo erro

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in >C:\wamp64\www\Projeto-EscolWeb\aluno-consulta.php on line 158

O código presente na linha é este

```
<h1>Documentos:</h1>
<?php $arrayDadosDocumentos = ObtemDocumentos($rg);
$idTipo = $arrayDadosDocumentos[2];?>
```

Já pesquisei sobre e sempre encontro a mesma solução, falando pra usar o ``, porém não sei como aplicar no meu código.

No momento é isso, agradeço pela atenção.

P.s.: Se precisarem de mais alguma informação, por favor, me avisem.

Código do `ObtemDocumento()`

```
function ObtemDocumentos($rg){
    include("conexao.php");

    $SQL ="SELECT D.* FROM documento D JOIN alunodocumento AD WHERE AD.RG = ".$rg." AND D.IdCaixa = AD.IdCaixa AND D.IdLote = AD.IdLote AND D.idTipoDoc = AD.idTipoDoc ORDER BY D.idTipoDoc;" ;

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $SQL);

    if (!$resultado) {
        $mensagem_erro  = 'Erro de sintaxe na query: ' . mysqli_error() . "<br>";
        $mensagem_erro .= 'SQL executado: ' . $SQL;
        $destino = 'http://localhost/Projeto-escolweb/php/erro.php?msg='.$mensagem_erro;
        header("Location: $destino");
        exit;
    }

   return $resultado;
```

Comment: O problema está em `ObtemDocumentos()` provavelmente falta o while com o `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: poderia colocar o código do `ObtemDocumentos`?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, código está no final da mesma.

Comment: Cara o código que eu postei funciona perfeitamente no seu caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser mais prático fazer a função retornar o array com os dados, então adicione a chamada de `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` no while e ao final dele retorne a variável (`$arr`) que contém os dados da consulta:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $SQL);
if (!$resultado) {
    $mensagem_erro  = 'Erro de sintaxe na query: ' . mysqli_error() . "<br>";
    $mensagem_erro .= 'SQL executado: ' . $SQL;
    $destino = 'http://localhost/Projeto-escolweb/php/erro.php?msg='.$mensagem_erro;
    header("Location: $destino");
    exit;
}

$arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $arr[] = $row;
}

return $arr;
```

Comment: Realmente, assim funciona melhor

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = ObtemDocumentos($rg);
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $idTipo = dados["idTipo"];
}
//se eu ajudei por favor vote na resposta
```

Comment: Não sei se dde fato não funcionou, ou se eu implementei sua esposta de maneira errada

Comment: O dado que ta dentro do while é fictício, só da um print_r na variável $dados e você vai ver que ele pega os dados um a um.

Comment: Sempre usei desse jeito

Comment: esse foi o retorno do print_r

>Array ( [0] => Array ( [IdCaixa] => 1 [IdLote] => a [idTipoDoc] => 1      >[Caminho] => uploads/01-a-9306088604-1-tmp [DataInclusao] => >2016-10-13 08:27:09 ) [1] => Array ( [IdCaixa] => 1 [IdLote] => b  >[idTipoDoc] => 2 [Caminho] => uploads/01-b-9306088604-2-tmp [DataInclusao] => 2016-10-13 08:32:00 ) )

Comment: E não eram esses os dados que você tava precisando ? kkkk Usa a resposta do outro cara, vai ficar mais fácil na hora de dar manutenção.

Comment: Realmente, são os dados que eu preciso, porém o retorno está todo bagunçado, vou ter que mexer um pouco kkkkkkkkk muito obrigado pela ajuda!